# ¿Cómo puedo obtener un Timer que se encuentra en un Control de Usuario?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

me he encontrado con el siguiente problema:
Tengo un formulario y dentro de él hay varios controles de usuario, los cuales tienen un timer. Quiero que, al llamar un control de usuario se desactive el timer del control que se cierra y se active el timer del control que se muestra (He creado un evento en el que mando el control de usuario de origen y el control de usuario de destino). Puedo acceder a los controles de cada control de usuario, pero no sé cómo puedo acceder al timer...

```
 public partial class Inicio : Form
{
    //Defino el evento con los parámetros que se van a enviar
    private delegate void cambiarVista(Object origen, Object destino);
    private event cambiarVista vistaCambiada;
    //Variables que almacenarán los controles de usuario
    private UserControl ctrlActual, ctrlNuevo;

    public Inicio()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //Al cargar el formulario se muestra este control de usuario:
        ctrlActual = dashBoard1;
        //Asignar evento al formulario:
        this.vistaCambiada += new cambiarVista(this.Inicio_vistaCambiada); 
    }

    //Esta función se ejecuta cuando se dispara el evento.
    private void Inicio_vistaCambiada(Object origen, Object destino)
    {
        ctrlOrigen = origen as UserControl;
        ctrlDestino = destino as UserControl;
        Console.WriteLine("Se cambió la vista\nOrigen: " + ctrlOrigen.Name + "\nDestino: " + ctrlDestino.Name);
        //Puedo acceder a los controles de cada control de usuario, pero no al timer
        foreach (Control c in ctrlDestino.Controls)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Control Padre: " + c.Name);
            foreach (Control cx in c.Controls)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Control Hijo: " + cx.Name);
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    //Esta función sirve para mostrar un control de usuario con la función BringToFront()
    private void mostrarUI(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = sender as Button;
        switch (btn.Name)
        {
            case "btnInicio":
                dashBoard1.BringToFront();
                ctrlNuevo = dashBoard1;
                break;
            case "btnSucursal":
                sucursales1.BringToFront();
                ctrlNuevo = sucursales1;
                break;
            case "btnEmpleado":
                empleados1.BringToFront();
                ctrlNuevo = empleados1;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        if (ctrlActual != ctrlNuevo)
        {
            vistaCambiada(ctrlActual, ctrlNuevo);
            ctrlActual = ctrlNuevo;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Prueba a poner el timer como `public` (en la ventana de propiedades del timer, Modifiers)

Comment: Tampoco pude así, ya había intentado. Pero gracias.